# How can I improve the proof of this statement with convexity?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

$A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. How do I prove that if $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ is
  convex then so is $A^{-1}(S) =\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax
  \in S\}$ ?

My proof:

$\forall t \in [0,1], ta+(1-t)b \in S$
Since $Ax\in S$, define $Aa'\in S, Ab'\in S$,

$\forall t \in [0,1], tAa'+(1-t)Ab' \in S$
$A(ta'+(1-t)b') \in S$
$A^{+}A(ta'+(1-t)b')= ta'+(1-t)b'\in A^{+}S$   (1), where $A^{+}$ is the pseudo-inverse of matrix $A$

Since $a',b' \in \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n,Ax\in S\}$ and $x \in A^{+}S$,
we have $a',b' \in A^{+}S$   (2).

I have my proof by timing $A^+$ (the pseudo-inverse of A) before $Ax$, however that's not a common method, moreover, $A^{+}A$ is not guaranteed to be an identity matrix, which may be problematic. Is there any more common technique in proving this statement?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overcomplicating a touch,

let $x,y\in A^{-1}(S)$ then if

$$tx + (1-t)y \in A^{-1}(S)$$ for all $t\in [0,1]$, the set is convex.

Now, let $z = tx+(1-t)y$, then $z\in A^{-1}(S)$ iff $Az \in S$. You can now write:

$$Az = ta + (1-t)b$$

letting $a=Ax, b=Ay$, both $a,b\in S$ since $x,y\in A^{-1}(S)$, by convexity $ta+(1-t)b\in S$ and therefore $z\in A^{-1}(S)$.